# performance testing apache and nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, nginx

Having just moved my server from apache to nginx, I'm wondering how I can go about gauging the performance of the server.

Are there any scripts available to run against the server?

Also, any good blog posts, documentation on performing performance tests against servers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking for recommendations about "Site performance" is about as meaningless as asking for a recommendation for "the best car".  It all depends on your workload.

The usual suspects are `ab` (Apache Benchmark) and `siege`; these will give you basic baselines for very basic service.  Beyond that, you really need to define what "performance" means for your site (raw throughput on a single static page, response time for a wide range of complex dynamic workflows, etc) and then work out a way to test your site against whatever benchmark is important to you.

As far as blog posts go... Google, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Httperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/httperf/) it is a tool for measuring web server performance. 
Also, please find [here](http://www.joeandmotorboat.com/2008/02/28/apache-vs-nginx-web-server-performance-deathmatch/) a results from some performance benchmarking between apache and nginx